# Como publicar sitio asp net core en ubuntu server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tengo un servidor NGINX en ubuntu server. Actualmente tengo un index.html (un hola mundo) en esta ruta:
/var/www/html únicamente con el fin de comprobar que el servidor esta funcionando correctamente. Pense que era igual que en el IIS que uno reemplaza el index.html del inetpub por la carpeta de la webapp publicada y con esa basta pero veo que no.
Como hago para publicar la carpeta de netcore y se visualize en lugar del index.html. Ya agregue esta línea de código en el proyecto webapp asp net core 3.1 como viene en la documentación :

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Citando exclusivamente la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1) oficial de Microsoft (que supongo que revisaste), tienes que:

Configurar tu sitio

> - Configure the app to handle secure local connections. For more information, see the HTTPS configuration section.
> - Remove https://localhost:5001 (if present) from the applicationUrl property in the Properties/launchSettings.json file.

luego publicar tu sitio para ponerlo en el servidor que corresponda

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release
```

luego configurar nginx para que sea proxy reverso en algún site en /etc/nginx/sites-available/ (usa default como ejemplo y crea uno nuevo)

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

luego haces un `ln -s` de ese archivo a /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ para que nginx lo sirva.

Y claro, usar en tu app la configuración que refieres para usar los headers correctos de las peticiones que son redirigidas por nginx.

Al final, puedes crear el archivo de definición del servicio si quieres que arranque en boot time.

IIS está fuertemente integrado y orientado a stacks de MS, no podemos esperar que todas las soluciones se usen igual.